# scp in a nested ssh session in python's paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, scp, channel

Basically, I have an issue with performing an scp over a nested SSH ssh session in Python. I used `paramiko` to establish an SSH from my local machine to another server, let's call this **A** and from **A**. I want to scp a file, let's call it **f** to a server **B**. Both servers have the same password. This is the code:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname=hostname, username=username, password=password)

chan = ssh.invoke_shell()    
chan.send('scp f username@B:.')
buff = ''
while not buff.endswith('\'s password: '):
    resp = chan.recv(9999)
    buff += resp

chan.send(password + '\n')
buff = ''
while not buff.endswith('$ '):
    resp = chan.recv(9999)
    buff += resp
```

I'm really not sure why this doesn't work. Any help is appreciated, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this in PyCharm? At what point does it fail, and are you getting any errors? It could be that the string in

```
buff.endswith('\'s password: '):
```

doesn't exactly match what's being outputted in the ssh session. Other than that it looks correct. I would recommend breakpointing at buff.endswith and inspecting whats actually in the buff and checking to see if it matches your string, as well as if your password is valid with that newline character in there.